# Connect to azure services (blob storage/servicebus) via a VPN

Tags: azure, vpn, azureservicebus, blobstorage

We are planning to connect to azure servicebus and blob storage from multiple sites. Is it possible to connect to them through a VPN instead of directly over the Internet to improve the security of the connection?

If it's possible can anyone advise how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, without know what kind of VPN you want/ what your networking set up is, I would suggest this:

https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-site-to-site-create/

Just put a machine on the azure network and send whatever bus data you want. You could even set up a proxy machine through that VPN if you are worried about publicly routed traffic.

Assuming they are in the same geo-location, any machine that is on the azure network that makes a request to blob storage or a service bus will never go through the internet. It will still use the public domain name but it will be sent through the azure networking fabric.

Without knowing the structure of what you're looking for, I would say the easiest way would be to set up an azure vm in the same geo-location.

This all being said, all traffic going to and from azure storage and service buses is encrypted and pretty safe.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This was one of the possibilities I was considering, however I was hoping for a solution that didnt require an additional VM (proxy) to live inside Azure when it's sole purpose would be to proxy traffic.

We already have a site-to-site IPSEC VPN. I was hoping there might be some kind of virtual way of connecting to Azures service but I haven't been able to find anything.

Comment: The other option is to configure your router to send all traffic to that domain "blank.servicebus.azure.com" through the site to site vpn tunnel. The name will still resolve but will never "go over the internet"